# StartActivityForResult() from child Activity

Tags: android

I have 3 activities. `Activity A` is parent Activity, `Activity B` is started as Child Activity of `Activity A`. Now when I called `StartActivityForResult` from `Activity B` for `Activity C`, Only `Activity A's onActivityresult` is called. I want to get Results in `Activity B's OnActivityResult`.

```
Intent it = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
getParent().startActivityForResult(it, REQUEST_CODE);
```

If i call like this.

```
startActivityForResult(it, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Both `onActivityResult` didn't called.

Any help will be Appreciated.

Comment: second way is correct

Comment: Are you using ActivityGroup or manifest attribute PARENT_ACTIVITY?

Comment: i am using ActivityGroup

Comment: @Bapu is ActivityGroup causing issue..?

Comment: Please try this [link][1] to get an idea about startActivityForResult.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/android-how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result

Answer (score 1):

Thanks For the help.
I solved my Problem. That was due to ActivityGroup. I use these methods.

```
Intent it = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
getParent().startActivityForResult(it, REQUEST_CODE);
```

This will gives you the result in Activity A's OnActivityResult. Yo need to call this from Activity A's result.

```
if (requestCode == 1) {     
            ActivityB activity = (ActivityB)getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity();
            activity.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        }
```

this will invoke Activity B's onActivityResult.

Answer (score 0):

Just call activity C from B using below line of code.

```
Intent it = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
startActivityForResult(it, REQUEST_CODE);
```

And you will get your result back on your "B" activities `onActivityResult()`;

Comment: in this way both OnActivityResult didn't called.